# UTF-8 strings are not looking right

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some strings Im getting from an API.

The api gave me strings like this:

[image]

But I suspect I need to somehow make these UTF-16?
Is there any way to do this with .NET? I know .NET prefers working with UTF-16...

```
public Task ParseTask(XElement task, bool singleTask)
{
    Task t = new Task();
    int id;
    int.TryParse(task.Attribute("id").Value, out id);
    t.ID = id;
    t.Title = singleTask ? task.Element("name").Value : task.Attribute("name").Value;
    t.IsComplete = task.Attribute("complete").Value == "1";
    t.IsBillable = task.Attribute("billable").Value == "1";

    if (task.Element("user").Attribute("id") != null)
    {
        t.UserID = task.Element("user").Attribute("id").Value;
        t.UserName = task.Element("user").Attribute("name").Value;
    }

    t.Description = task.Element("description").Value;
    decimal pph;
    decimal.TryParse(task.Element("price_per_hour").Value, out pph);
    t.PricePerHour = pph;

    decimal bh;
    decimal.TryParse(task.Element("budget_hours").Value, out bh);
    t.BudgetHours = bh;
    int pid;
    int.TryParse(task.Element("project").Attribute("id").Value, out pid);
    t.ProjectID = pid;

    int tlid;
    int.TryParse(task.Element("tasklist").Attribute("id").Value, out tlid);
    t.TaskListID = tlid;

    return t;
}
```

--

```
 public List<Task> GetProjectTasks(int projectID)
        {
            List<Task> list = new List<Task>();

            string args = String.Format("project_id={0}", projectID);
            string uri = CreateURI("paymo.tasks.findByProject", args);
            string reply = client.DownloadString(uri);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(reply);
            if (IsOk(doc))
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> tasks =
                    doc.Element("response").Element("tasks").Elements();

                foreach (var task in tasks)
                {
                    list.Add(ParseTask(task, false));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }



            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Please show the code that retrieves the strings.

Comment: It seems more likely you've read the strings as UTF8 when they were saved as ANSI.

Comment: It is from an XML file sent by the server...

Comment: Please show how you actually get that `XElement` instance that is passed into the `ParseTask` method.

Comment: I just need to know, how do I tell  .net that my document is utf-8 encoded and to auto treat it like utf-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET uses by default UTF-16 strings. The function `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`. 
can help you by passing in the data as a `Byte[]` array and retrieving an UTF-16 string.

See: [Encoding.GetString Method (Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx)